# Ejabberd clustering not working

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I follow this website link for ejabberd clustering  http://chad.ill.ac/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql
everything is fine its shows two nodes running db and web admin also two node master and slave but if i shtdown master or slave node other one node not continue the process what should i do for if one node is down otherone is continue the process.

Comment: I don't understand what "other one node not continue the process" means. Please read the site's help on asking questions and edit your question to include the code you run and the error messages you get.

Comment: if i login slave in mater side log its  Failed authentication for ejabberd@slave from IP 192.168.13.58 ({{192,168,13,58},55310}) this error is occur

Answer (score 0):

Mnesia behaves as a multi-master database. But if you down the nodes, the restart process should be in reverse order. If you have node1 and node2 and you kill node 1 and after that, you kill node2, then you should restart node2 first and then node1. That's because Mnesia thinks that the last updated node is the last one.